# Message content intent is not enabled. Prefix commands may not work as expected unless you enable this

Tags: discord.py

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I have all the intents enabled as seen in the image below.

[image: All intents enabled]

This is my first project** in discord.py, and I don't really understand some things.
Here is the code I have (hoping this is relavant):

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord import Interaction
from nextcord.ext import commands

intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
command_prefix = '!'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix, intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  print(command_prefix)

testserver = 988598060538015815

@nextcord.slash_command(name = "hello", description = "Bot Says Hello", guild_ids = [testserver])
async def hellocommand(interaction: Interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message("yoooo")


client.run("my token")
```

Comment: the privileged intents also have to be enabled in the code...

Comment: Try: `intents = nextcord.Intents.all()`

Answer (score 4):

change `intents = nextcord.Intents.default()` to `intents = nextcord.Intents.all()`