# Discord bot not reply

Tags: javascript, discord, chatbot

I setup node.js
Bot is active but but it doesn't answer

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is running!");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!")
})

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "ping") {
    message.channel.send("pong");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.token);
```

i don't know what to do
thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent to be able to read the content of the messageCreate event:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is running!");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!")
})

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "MESSAGE_CONTENT"]});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "ping") {
    message.channel.send("pong");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: Program enters crash loop.

Comment: You have to enable the message content intent on your developer portal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694788/message-content-intent-is-not-enabled-prefix-commands-may-not-work-as-expected